# Pick out the index of the first non-NA value preceding and succeeding an index in R?

Tags: r, na

I have a question about picking out the index first non `NA` value preceding and succeeding an index in a list. For example, in the list below,  `values[index]` is NA. So I want a function which would return a before index, (which in this example would be 3, because 0.5 is the first non-NA value) and an after index (which in this example would be 7 because 0.3 is the first value after the index which is not NA).

Thanks for your help! I think I might be able to do it with a for-loop, but am trying to avoid this.

```
 index = 5
 values=c(0.4, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 0.3 ,NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.3,0.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
index = 5
values=c(0.4, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 0.3 ,NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.3,0.5)
```

then the two values you are looking for are

```
max(which(!is.na(values))[which(!is.na(values))<index])
[1] 3

min(which(!is.na(values))[which(!is.na(values))>index])
[1] 7
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could also do this in one `which` like:

```
#Max
which(!is.na(values) & seq_along(values) > index)[1]
#[1] 7

#Min
tail(which(!is.na(values) & seq_along(values) < index), 1)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: @Ryan, good point he does say strictly *before* and *after*. Just updated for `<` and `>`

Answer (score 1):

An option is to filter `vector` to split in `2-parts`(`1:index` and `index:length`). Then find first `non-NA` from both parts as:

```
#Data
index = 5
values=c(0.4, NA, 0.5, NA, NA, NA, 0.3 ,NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 0.3,0.5) 

#Min
max(which(!is.na(values[1:index])))
#[1] 3

#Max  - which will return offset form `index`. Hence, we need to adjust it
min(which(!is.na(values[index:length(values)])))+(index-1)
#[1] 7
```